# Why is Pyzo throwing errors every time I try to set a variable?

Tags: python, variables, random

I'm trying to code a simple dice game in Pyzo, as I took a basic class (several months ago) that used this program. I'm trying to get back into coding with it, and I can not figure out why every time I try to set a variable, it throws a syntax error. It's extremely annoying. Please keep in mind I am at a very basic level of Python, and would like to get better.

Comment: please include your code so we can maybe help you.

Comment: In general , please provide your relevant code and the error that you are facing so that we are able to help you